# How to CAST one attribute to INTEGER then group and sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I would like to do the following with a query/SQL in Rails:

1. Collect a batch of Orders, selecting `:buyer_id` and `:weight_lb`.
2. Convert every weight_lb from a string (like `"12.3lb"` to an integer `12`).
3. Sum all the `weight_lb` and group by `buyer_id`.

The output should look like: `{buyer_id_1: 65, buyer_id_2: 190}`, etc., where each number is the sum of each buyer's order weights.

This is what I've tried:

```
Order.find_by_sql("SELECT \"orders\".\"id\", \"orders\".\"buyer_id\", CAST(\"orders\".\"weight_lb\" AS DECIMAL) FROM \"orders\" LIMIT 500 OFFSET 1000")
=> [
  #<Order:0x0000000118054830 id: 15076494, buyer_id: 22918, weight_lb: "315.0">,
  #<Order:0x0000000118054918 id: 15076495, buyer_id: 22918, weight_lb: "110.0">,
  ...]
```

Despite `CAST() as DECIMAL`, the weight is still output as a string.
When I try to `CAST() as INTEGER`, it fails entirely with `PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "315.0" (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)`

What I would ideally like to have is:

```
{
  15076494: 425,     # Sum of all weights for the ID 15076494
  15076495: 0,
  15076496: 95, ...
}
```

I'm just not sure how to get there efficiently using Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a combination of REPLACE, CAST and SUM operations

```
Order
  .select("buyer_id, SUM(CAST(REPLACE(weight_lb, 'lb', '') AS DECIMAL)) AS weight_lb")
  .group("buyer_id")
  .limit(500)
  .offset(1000)
```

**The generated SQL will be:**

```sql
SELECT "orders"."buyer_id", SUM(CAST(REPLACE("orders"."weight_lb", 'lb', '') AS DECIMAL)) AS weight_lb 
FROM "orders" 
GROUP BY "orders"."buyer_id" 
LIMIT 500 
OFFSET 1000
```

Let me know if it helps. :)

Comment: @engineersmnky  To use `Model#[]` to access arel attribute, we need to add this method in `models/application_record.rb` class

`def self.[](attribute) = arel_table[attribute]`